# Pyschools Topic 13- 2. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

Topic 13: Question 2: Create a function that appends the name and email to the end of a named file.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def addEmail(filename, name, email):
    f = open('filename', 'a') 

    f.write("%s\n" % name)
    f.write("%s\n" % email)
    f.close()

    return f
```

This is the output that I get on pyschools website:

```
Test Cases                                          Expected Result Returned Result Result
addEmail('email.txt', 'john', 'john@gmail.com').closed  True          True  

Private Test Cases                                   Passed            Failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the sample output:

```
>>> addEmail('emails.txt', 'Mary', 'mary@gmail.com') # content is 'Mary mary@gmail.com\n'
>>> addEmail('emails.txt', 'John', 'john@gmail.com') # content is 'Mary mary@gmail.com\nJohn john@gmail.com\n'
```

Note that in that output, the name and email are on the same line, separated by a space.  You are putting the name and email on separate lines.  Try changing your code to the following:

```
f.write("%s %s\n" % (name, email))
```

Comment: @f-j Thank you so much for answering my question. Seems like I was not paying enough attention at what the exercise wanted me to do. It works  now and the solution was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

One thing wrong is that your filename is `'filename'` in all cases.  It should probably be the variable `filename`, not a string.